# How do I send gridview as excel email attachment

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel, gridview

I know I can export my gridview to excel without using `VerifyRenderingInServerForm(Control control)` like this:

```
 Response.Clear();
        Response.Buffer = true;

        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition",
         "attachment;filename=filename.xls");
        Response.Charset = "";
        Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
        StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
        HtmlTextWriter hw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);

        GridView1.AllowPaging = false;
        GridView1.DataBind();

        //Change the Header Row back to white color
        GridView1.HeaderRow.Style.Add("background-color", "#003c74");
        GridView1.HeaderRow.Style.Add("color", "#ffffff");

        for (int i = 0; i < GridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            GridViewRow row = GridView1.Rows[i];

            //Change Color back to white
            row.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;

            //Apply text style to each Row
            row.Attributes.Add("class", "textmode");

            //Apply style to Individual Cells of Alternating Row
            if (i % 2 != 0)
            {
                row.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.AliceBlue;
            }
        }
        GridView1.RenderControl(hw);

        //style to format numbers to string
        string style = @"<style> .textmode { mso-number-format:\@; } </style>";
        Response.Write(style);
        Response.Output.Write(sw.ToString());
        Response.Flush();
        Response.End();
```

How do I modify this to use the `Memory Stream` in order to send this in an email as an attachment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just pull the data out of the string writer into a `byte[]` and then create a `MemoryStream` passing it the byte array data, finally use the `Attachements` collection of the `MailMessage` class to attach it to the email to send, like this:

```
MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();

System.Text.Encoding theEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII;
byte[] theByteArray = theEncoding.GetBytes(sw.ToString());
MemoryStream theMemoryStream = new MemoryStream(theByteArray, false);
mail.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(theMemoryStream, "YOUR_FILE_NAME.xls"));

// Do remainder of your email settings here, To, From, Subject, etc.
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your StringWriter into a StreamWriter and pass a MemoryStream into it. So change the following:

```
StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
HtmlTextWriter hw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
```

To:

```
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(ms);
HtmlTextWriter hw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
```

Then you should have a populated memory stream after your call to GridView.RendControl