# Trouble with attaching gridview to email in DotNetNuke

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, dotnetnuke

I was looking around and found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20476671/how-do-i-send-gridview-as-excel-email-attachment). It is quite similar to what I want to accomplish the only problem is that when I run the script nothing happens unless I remove the `{ attachment }` line. However, if I remove that line I do not get my attachment.

```
private void SendEmail()
    {
        StringBuilder message;
        Attachment attachment;


        string strOrderType;


        if (lblRequestType.Text == "Order Request")
        {
            strOrderType = "Order Request";
        }
        else
        {
            strOrderType = "Return Request";
        }

        string strName = txtFname.Text + " " + txtLname.Text;
        string strOrderNum = lblOrderNum.Text;

        string strSubject = "Request:" + strOrderNum + " - " + strName + " " + strOrderType;

        StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
        HtmlTextWriter htmlWriter = new HtmlTextWriter(writer);
        GridView gridView = new GridView();
        gridView.DataSource = sdsOrders;
        gridView.AutoGenerateColumns = true;
        gridView.DataBind();
        gridView.HeaderRow.Style.Add("background-color", "#003c74");
        gridView.HeaderRow.Style.Add("color", "#ffffff");
        for (int i = 0; i < gridView.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            GridViewRow row = gridView.Rows[i];

            //Change Color back to white
            row.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;

            //Apply text style to each Row
            row.Attributes.Add("class", "textmode");

            //Apply style to Individual Cells of Alternating Row
            if (i % 2 != 0)
            {
                row.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.AliceBlue;
            }
        }
        gridView.RenderControl(htmlWriter);
        htmlWriter.Close();

        System.Text.Encoding theEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII;
        byte[] theByteArray = theEncoding.GetBytes(writer.ToString());
        MemoryStream theMemoryStream = new MemoryStream(theByteArray, false);
        //Visitor Message


        if (txtEmail.Text.Length > 0)
        {
            message = new StringBuilder();
            message.AppendLine("<h4 style=\"font-family: verdana, arial;\">Company Name</h4>");
            message.AppendLine("<p style=\"font-size: small; font-family: verdana, arial;\">Dear " + txtFname.Text + ",</p>");
            message.AppendLine("<p style=\"font-size: small; font-family: verdana, arial;\">Company Message.</p>");
            message.AppendLine("Your Confirmation number is: " + strOrderNum);

            attachment = new Attachment(theMemoryStream, strSubject);
            Mail.SendMail("Address1@none.net", txtEmail.Text, "", "Address1@none.net",
                "Address1@none.net", MailPriority.Normal, "Company Message", MailFormat.Html, Encoding.UTF8, message.ToString(),
                new List<Attachment>() { attachment }, null, null, null, null, Host.EnableSMTPSSL);
        }

        //Internal Message
        message = new StringBuilder();
        message.AppendLine("<p style=\"font-size: small; font-family: verdana, arial;\">YAY it worked.</p>");


        // need to create new reference to attachment, cannot use same reference to send email twice
        attachment = new Attachment(theMemoryStream, strSubject);
        Mail.SendMail("Address1@none.net", "Address1@none.net", "", "Address1@none.net",
            "", MailPriority.Normal, strSubject, MailFormat.Html, Encoding.UTF8, message.ToString(),
            new List<Attachment>() { attachment }, null, null, null, null, Host.EnableSMTPSSL);

    }
```

Please tell me where I am going wrong here

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit more on 'nothing happens'?  Does the email still get queued in the outgoing bin?  Is it possible your email provider is blocking due to the attachment not specifying a content type?  Have you tried saving to a file on disk, then using that file as the attachment?

Comment: @KyleB. I have tried saving the file to disk and it saves. But I need to use it as an attachment. By nothing happens I mean that the email does not get sent at all.

Comment: Sure, I meant to save it to disk, then as the argument to the constructor of the 'Attachment' class, pass the filename.  I had a theory your email was being blocked because the attachment had no mime type, and that could be resolved by using the full filename.

Comment: I almost wonder if it is another function that could be causing the issue

Comment: @KyleB. can you give me an example of what you mean here?

Comment: Yeah, per the documentation (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.attachment(v=vs.110).aspx) it looks like you are using the 3rd constructor (Stream, String), but string should be the content type, not the subject variable you have passed to it.